# Date comparision in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript

I am facing this weird behavoure inside my javascript code:-

```
var expirydate = item.get_item('ExpireDate');
alert("expirydate = "+ expirydate);

var modifieddate = item.get_item('Modified');
alert("modifieddate = "+ modifieddate);

var currentdate = new Date();
alert("currentdate = "+currentdate);

expirydate.setDate(expirydate.getDate() + 1);
var expiredperiod = expirydate;
alert("expired period = " + expiredperiod );
```

where the above returned the following:-

```
expirydate = Mon Jun 10 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)

modifieddate = Mon Jun 10 2019 22:12:59 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)

currentdate = Wed Jun 12 2019 23:33:07 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)

expired period = Tue Jun 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

but i have this comparison

```
if (expirydate != null && modifieddate  < expirydate && currentdate > expiredperiod )
```

and in my above case the if statment passed .. although i can see that in my case the `modifieddate` which is `Mon Jun 10 2019 22:12:59 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)` is greater than `expirydate` which is `Mon Jun 10 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)` which should cause the `if` statement to fail.. so not sure why my `if` statement passed?

here is the full code

```
function showexpiry(){

    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
    var item = list.getItemById(_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId);

    ctx.load(list);
    ctx.load(item);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync( 
          function(){ 

            var expirydate = item.get_item('ExpireDate');
            alert("expirydate = "+ expirydate);

            var modifieddate = item.get_item('Modified');
            alert("modifieddate = "+ modifieddate);

             var currentdate = new Date();
            alert("currentdate = "+currentdate);

            var tempdate = new Date();

            tempdate.setDate(tempdate.getDate() + 1);
            //alert(tempdate);

            expirydate.setDate(expirydate.getDate() + 1);
            var expiredperiod = expirydate;
            alert("expired period = " + expiredperiod );

if (expirydate != null && modifieddate  < expirydate && currentdate > expiredperiod )

{
statusDesc2 = SP.UI.Status.addStatus("Warning, this page has expired and exceed the expired period of 1 day");
                SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(statusDesc2, 'red');

}


          }
        , function(err){ 
        alert(err);
        });
}
```

i added another variable for the expiry date as follow:-

```
function showexpiry(){

    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
    var item = list.getItemById(_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId);

    ctx.load(list);
    ctx.load(item);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync( 
          function(){ 

            var expirydate = item.get_item('ExpireDate');
            var expirydate2 = item.get_item('ExpireDate');

            alert("expirydate = "+ expirydate);

            var modifieddate = item.get_item('Modified');
            alert("modifieddate = "+ modifieddate);

             var currentdate = new Date();
            alert("currentdate = "+currentdate);

            var tempdate = new Date();

            tempdate.setDate(tempdate.getDate() + 1);
            //alert(tempdate);

            expirydate2.setDate(expirydate2.getDate() + 1);
            var expiredperiod = expirydate2;
            alert("expired period = " + expiredperiod );

if (expirydate != null && modifieddate  < expirydate && currentdate > expiredperiod )

{
statusDesc2 = SP.UI.Status.addStatus("Warning, this page has expired and exceed the expired period of 1 day");
                SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(statusDesc2, 'red');

}
```

Comment: I don't think you've posted enough code for anybody to be able to help. JavaScript date comparisons done properly do in fact work, so there must be something going on that only you can see currently.

Comment: @Pointy i posted the javascript code + the results of the code + the if statement which failed.. not sure what i need to provide?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tbh96s7v/ - your code (hard coded the dates) produces the result you expect - so, not sure why you are not getting the result you are getting

Comment: @Pointy i provided the full javascript code

Comment: @JaromandaX same happened to me..

Comment: @testtest - try providing executable code that behaves the way you claim

Comment: Your code can not result with "expired period" and "expiry date" having different values - so your output is misleading you

Comment: @Jaromanda X you are correct, i provided another variable named `expirydate2 ` but did nit fix the issue.. can you check my updated code?

Comment: Have you verified that the two "copies" of that date are actually distinct? `console.log()` is a much more useful tool than `alert()` to track what's going on in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You output `expirydate` here

```
var expirydate = item.get_item('ExpireDate');
alert("expirydate = "+ expirydate);
```

but then, before using it in the comparison, you alter `expirydate` here

```
expirydate.setDate(expirydate.getDate() + 1);
```

So your "alert" outputs are misleading you

What you think you are doing

```js
expirydate = new Date('Mon Jun 10 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100');
modifieddate = new Date('Mon Jun 10 2019 22:12:59 GMT+0100');
currentdate = new Date('Wed Jun 12 2019 23:33:07 GMT+0100');
expiredperiod = new Date('Tue Jun 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100');
console.log(expirydate != null && modifieddate  < expirydate && currentdate > expiredperiod )
```

What your code is actually doing

```js
//expirydate = new Date('Mon Jun 10 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100');
modifieddate = new Date('Mon Jun 10 2019 22:12:59 GMT+0100');
currentdate = new Date('Wed Jun 12 2019 23:33:07 GMT+0100');
expiredperiod = new Date('Tue Jun 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100');
expirydate = expiredperiod // <==== this is the key to your issue
console.log(expirydate != null && modifieddate  < expirydate && currentdate > expiredperiod )
```

now, regarding your late edit

does

```
item.get_item('ExpireDate')
```

return a Date object?

if so, then

```
        var expirydate = item.get_item('ExpireDate');
        var expirydate2 = item.get_item('ExpireDate');
```

will result in both of those variables referring to the same object

change one, you change the other ...

try

```
var expirydate = item.get_item('ExpireDate');
var expiredperiod = new Date(expiryDate);
expiredperiod.setDate(expiredperiod.getDate()+1);
```

Comment: yes you are correct, now i added another variable to store the expiry date, but this did not fix the issue.. i updated my original question with the new code..

Comment: I've already addressed your new code ... if `get_item` returns the SAME Date object, then changing `expirydate` will also change `expirydate` - that's how objects work in javascript - see the very end of the answer for a probable solution

Comment: you are 100% correct as i moved all the  alerts to be after the variable settings and i can see that `expirydate ` & `expirydate2 `& "expiredperiod" will be the same !!

Comment: did not know about if 2 variables reference the same `item.get_item('ExpireDate')` then modifying one variable will modify the other.. your code worked for me thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

I mean you try to compare invalid date formats, aren't you? Try to add `new Date` around `item.getItem(...)`.

```
var expirydate = new Date (item.get_item('ExpireDate'));
alert("expirydate = "+ expirydate);

var modifieddate = new Date(item.get_item('Modified'));
alert("modifieddate = "+ modifieddate);

var currentdate = new Date();
alert("currentdate = "+currentdate);

expirydate.setDate(expirydate.getDate() + 1);
var expiredperiod = expirydate;
alert("expired period = " + expiredperiod );
```

Comment: but the results inside the popups are valid and consistent .. is this correct?

Comment: can i ask you to remove the "TDM" from your code.. thanks @ `var expirydate = new Date (item.get_item('TDMExpireDate'));`